# Exception when adding custom tag library to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jstl

I have the same problem as [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16206318/using-jstl-core-lib-fails-when-creating-custom-tag) from almost 2 years ago.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/myLib" prefix="myLib" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

I have these two lines in my JSP. Originally I was only using the JSTL core library and everything worked well. As soon as I add a custom library, I get an exception like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.toString(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:129)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2979)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.toString(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1321)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.OutSupport.out(OutSupport.java:211)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.OutSupport.doStartTag(OutSupport.java:132)
at org.apache.jsp.FormTest_jsp._jspx_meth_c_out_3(FormTest_jsp.java:306)
at org.apache.jsp.FormTest_jsp._jspx_meth_c_forEach_1(FormTest_jsp.java:256)
at org.apache.jsp.FormTest_jsp._jspService(FormTest_jsp.java:83)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:575)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:546)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
at form.FormServlet.processRequest(FormServlet.java:60)
at form.FormServlet.doPost(FormServlet.java:89)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

If I remove either of the two taglib directives, everything works correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<taglib version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd">
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <short-name>mylib</short-name>
  <uri>/WEB-INF/tlds/myLib</uri>
  <tag>
    <name>beaner</name>
    <tagclass>form.BeanTagHandler</tagclass>
    <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
  </tag>
</taglib>
```

tld is very minimal to try to get this working.

Would appreciate it if anyone can offer some insight as to what the problem may be. Thanks.

EDIT: Found the source of the problem.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Attribute Name</th>
<th>Attribute Value</th></tr>
<c:forEach var="a" items="${applicationScope}">
<tr>
<td> <c:out value="${a.key}"/> </td>
<td> <c:out value="${a.value}" /> </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

The problematic part is the c:out for ${a.value}. The jsp works fine without it.
For some reason it works fine when I don't import my custom tag library. Any ideas as to why trying to c:out the values of the applicationScope would cause problems?

Comment: Paste your whole jsp and your custom tag + definition + config.

Comment: tomcat/jetty version?

Comment: In your stacktrace, the expection is generated while executing a `<c:out` inside a `<c:forEach`, I don't understand how removing the jstl import, while leaving yours, will cause the same exception.

Comment: could you share with us your custom tag lib definition?

Comment: Using glassfish 4.1 on netbeans. Also to clarify, it works when I remove the jstl import while I leave mine. This leads me to believe that importing the custom tag lib breaks jstl somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured out the problem. There is an attribute called com.sun.jsp.taglibraryCache in applicationScope that is Class ConcurrentHashMap. It seems that importing another tag library causes the toString method of the class to give a NullPointerException. I fixed my problem by using c:catch to catch the exception.